# Finding key for Hill Cipher

Tags: linear-algebra, cryptography

Suppose a Hill cipher with block size 2 is given, with known plaintext and corresponding encryption
$E_K( ‘guns’ ) = ‘YGJC’$
What are the possibilities for the key $K$?

My initial thought was to setup:
$$KX=Y$$
Where $X$ is the matrix of the plaintext (guns) converted into columns of numbers where $a=0,b=1,...$, and $Y$ is the matrix of cipher text. I then solved for the key matrix $K=YX^{-1}$ and got

$$K=\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{-63}{38} & \frac{129}{76} \\ \frac{-17}{38} & \frac{33}{76}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}$$

I feel modular arithmetic should be involved with the matrix, but I'm not sure how since the textbook doesn't mention anything nor did my professor do any examples. I'm under the impression that there might not even be a valid key matrix since the plaintext matrix is:

$$X=\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
6 & 13 \\ 20 & 18
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}$$

And $\det{(X)}=-152$ which is not coprime to $26$ so there's no multiplicative inverse $\mod{26}$??? I'm lost at how to find all the possible keys

Comment: You need to find the inverse of the key $K$
to $\bmod 26$. You need the inverse of the key, not the plaintext so one need an invertible $$ over $\bmod 26$ since encryption must be reversible to be meaningful.

Comment: @kelalaka I need an “invertible $X$ over $\mod{26}$”? Isn’t that what I showed I don’t have, that $X$’s determinant is divisible by $2$?

Comment: @kelalaka Why do I need to find the inverse of the key? How would I do that if I don’t even know if I found $K$ correctly?

Comment: This is due to some plaintext ciphertext pairs, do you get some others? Still, we can solve [How to determine the key-matrix of a Hill cipher where the encrypted-message-matrix is not invertible?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/911907/338051)

Comment: @kelalaka We don't get any others. Just that guns is encrypted to YGJC. I saw such an example of *that* in my textbook where there's a probable plaintext somewhere in a longer string of encrypted text.

Comment: @kelalaka I found $K$ in the usual inverting of matrices (no $\mod 26$). Is that good enough?

Comment: no, the system is working in $\bmod 26$, the inverse will not work there.

Comment: @kelalaka so how do I find the key matrix if I need to invert an invertible matrix? I don't think I can shift the ciphertext as vectors since the ciphertext given is as big as the plane text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your equation $\ KX=Y\ $ as a set of four linear equations mod $26$ for the four unknown entries $\ k_{11},$$\,k_{21},$$\,k_{12},$$\,k_{22}\ $ of $\ K\ $:
$$
\pmatrix{6&20&0&0\\
13&18&0&0\\0&0&6&20\\0&0&13&18}\pmatrix{k_{11}\\k_{12}\\k_{21}\\k_{22}}=\pmatrix{24\\9\\6\\2}\ .
$$
Because the integers modulo any prime form a field , the easiest way to find all the solutions (if any) of these equations is to find all the solutions mod $2$ and all the solutions mod $13$ and use the [Chinese remainder algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) to combine them together to get all the solutions of the original equations mod $26$.  The coefficient matrix of the equations is singular mod $2$, with rank $2$.  The equations are nevertheless *consistent* mod $2$, so you should be able to find a two-dimensional space of solutions for $\ k_{11},$$\,k_{21},$$\,k_{12},k_{22}\ $ mod $2$.  Since there are only $\ 2\ $ elements in the field  of integers mod $2$, this means that that there will be only four solution in your entire solution space. You should find, however, that two of these give you a matrix $\ K\ $ which isn't invertible mod $2$, so these can't provide you with a valid solution for $\ K\ $

The coefficient matrix of the above system of equations is *non-singular* mod $13$, which means there's a *unique* solution for $\ k_{11},$$\,k_{21},$$\,k_{12},k_{22}\ $ mod $13$, and this solution will give you a matrix $\ K\ $ which is invertible mod $13$.   Having two solutions mod $2$ and a unique solution for $\ K\ $ mod $13$ means that you will have two solutions mod $26$. Once you've found them you can check that they both satisfy your equation $\ KX=Y\ $, so without further information you have no way of telling which of them is the actual key.

> $$K=\pmatrix{11&7\\4&3}\ \ \text{ or }\ \  \pmatrix{11&20\\4&3}$$

**Response to queries from the OP in comments below**

The equations for $\ k_{11},$$\,k_{21},$$\,k_{12},$$\,k_{22}\ $ above decouple into two pairs of two equations, one pair for $\ k_{11}\ $ and $\ k_{12}\ $ and the other for $\ k_{21}\ $ and $\ k_{22}\ $. To illustrate the procedure of [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) mod $26$ I'll use it below to solve the first pair of equations for $\ k_{11}\ $ and $\ k_{12}\ .$ While the procedure is very similar to normal Gaussian elimination, all the elementary row operations you use must be reversible mod $26.$  This means that you can never multiply an equation by $13$ or an even number.  Here is a sequence of elementary row operations for reducing the pair of linear congruences
$$
6k_{11}+20k_{12}\equiv24\pmod{26}\\
13k_{11}+18k_{12}\equiv9\pmod{26}
$$
to an equivalent pair for $\ k_{11}\ $ and $\ k_{12}\ $ separately.  All the arithmetic in the procedure is carried out mod $26$.
\begin{align}
&\begin{array}{cc|cc}
k_{11}&k_{12}\\
\hline
6&20&24\\
13&18&9
\end{array}\\
&\begin{array}{cc|cc}
k_{11}&k_{12}\\
\hline
6&20&24\\
1&4&13&r_2\rightarrow r_2-2r_1
\end{array}\\
&\begin{array}{cc|cc}
k_{11}&k_{12}\\
\hline
0&22&24&r_1\rightarrow r_1-6r_2\\
1&4&13
\end{array}\\
&\begin{array}{cc|cc}
k_{11}&k_{12}\\
\hline
0&2&14&r_1\rightarrow 19r_1\\
1&4&13
\end{array}\\
&\begin{array}{cc|cc}
k_{11}&k_{12}\\
\hline
0&2&14\\
1&0&11&r_2\rightarrow r_2-2r_1
\end{array}
\end{align}
Thus, the above congruences are equivalent to
$$
2k_{12}\equiv14\pmod{26}\\
k_{11}\equiv11\pmod{26}\  
$$
and the first of these has *two* solutions mod $26$—namely $\ k_{12}\equiv7\pmod{26}\ $ and $\ k_{12}\equiv20\pmod{26}\ $.

Comment: We haven't even learned the Chinese Remainder Theorem yet. Could you get all the matrices $K$ by solving a system of congruences?

Comment: And will using linear congruences account for the $2$ invertible key matrices?

Comment: Yes, you can obtain all the possible key matrices by using a form of Gaussian elimination mod $26$ to solve the equations.  If you haven't learned the Chinese remainder theorem, however, I think it's a bit much to expect you to be able to discover how to do this by yourself without any instruction.  For what it's worth, I'll add an outline of the procedure for the first two equations (for $\ k_{11}\ $ and $\ k_{12}\ $) to my answer. You might then like to try applying it to the second pair of equations for $\ k_{21}\ $ and $\ k_{22}\ $.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is great

Comment: One last question, you said "you can never multiply an equation by 13
 or an even number" but you subtracted $2$ times the first row from the 2nd?

Comment: You can add  *any* multiple of any row to (or subtract it from) any other because the row you've added or subtracted *doesn't change*.  You can therefore always reverse this operation by subtracting the same multiple of this unchanged row from (or adding it to) the row you did change.  What you can't do is *replace* any row by an even multiple of itself or by itself multiplied by $13$.  You can't reverse such an operation mod $26$ because division by $13$ or by an even number isn't possible mod $26$.